# Expected an identifier and Expected to find ')' error

Tags: flutter, http, http-status-code-404

I am beginner coder and i dont understand how to resolve this error

```dart
Future<http.Response> fetchData(String query) async {
    return  http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://laravelsyd-fypfinalver.herokuapp.com/getBusService'),

      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: { 
        jsonEncode({'bus_stop_id': busCode})
      },
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          final List<dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
          dataList = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(data);
          setState(() {// Update the state to trigger a rebuild with the fetched data
             dataList = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(data);
          },);
        } else {
          print (response.statusCode);
        }
        );
  }
```

error:
Expected an identifier.
Expected to find ')'

where should i put the if to check the status code? do i need to make new class?

i tried rearranging the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code

```
  Future<http.Response> fetchData(String query) async {
var response = await http.post(
    "https://laravelsyd-fypfinalver.herokuapp.com/getBusService",
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode({'bus_stop_id': busCode}));

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final List<dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
  dataList = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(data);
  setState(
    () {
      // Update the state to trigger a rebuild with the fetched data
      dataList = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(data);
    },
  );
} else {
  print(response.statusCode);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code hope this will solve your problem.

```dart
Future<http.Response> fetchData(String query) async {
final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://laravelsyd-fypfinalver.herokuapp.com/getBusService'),

      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: { 
        jsonEncode({'bus_stop_id': busCode})
      },
       
        );
return response;
  }
```

Comment: it did resolve the error but now it has another error - [Invalid request body "{{"bus_stop_id":"1076"}}".]